# Can mount but cannot umount without password

Tags: filesystems, unmounting

I want to mount/umount a directory on an nfs directory without root privileges or any password request. I modified `/etc/fstab` in this way:

```
<IP address>:/mydir     /mnt    nfs     rw,user,noauto          0 0
```

`mount /mnt/` works without asking me for the password. However:

```
$> umount /mnt/
```

Shows the following error message:

```
umount.nfs: /mnt: not found
umount.nfs: /mnt: not found
```

`sudo umount /mnt/` does the job correctly, but asks for the password.

Any hint?

Comment: Not exactly. Please note that I don't want to mount anything without sudo: just the directory mydir in nfs.